# How to add custom meta filter to WooCommerce Analytics?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filter, hook

I need to generate reports based on custom meta added to orders. Instead of reinventing the wheel, I really think this should be doable by adding custom filter to all the available WooCommerce analytics.
[image: expected custom filter display]

I found [one tutorial](https://developer.woocommerce.com/2020/02/20/extending-wc-admin-reports) very near to it but not really able to grasp it as it involved js compile stuff and compatible for version before 4.0

Above example would work for me if there's a way to add custom filter option without need of js customization.

Could anyone please point to other examples or least provide quick snippet on how to add filter via add_filter() or other hooks?